# React re-renders on keypress

Tags: reactjs

I dont even know how to start describing this, but here goes.

I have a Questionnaire app.
This consists of a listing of questionnaires.
If you click on a questionnaire it opens a Modal window to the Questionnaire.
This Questionnaire modal then has a Carousel with questions.
Each question is another component and each question can consist of 4 or less objects e.g. (date field, dropdowns and a text fields)

My problem here is that on every keyPress in a text field, React rerenders.
Now on this text field, the event is set on `onBlur`, but yet on every key press it initiates a re-render.
This rerender clears the form of all its values for a second, but as soon as I lose focus on the text field, it populates all the form values again.

What am I missing?

```
"react": "^15.4.0",
"react-redux": "^4.3.0",
```

[image]

HERE I started typing in the last text box

[image]

Comment: You need to post code samples - we can't do anything with pictures. There could be all sorts of reasons for this, and *some* rerendering is going to be desirable on every keypress otherwise the UI would not be updated. It sounds like your components might be getting continuously remounted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a state hook such as `useState`/`useReducer` so that the state is preserved between renders.

You can then control the value of the fields directly from this state. You will also update the state by handling the events `onChange`/`onBlur`.

With a dynamic number of lines, the shape of your state is an array of objects. To help implement this, you will likely need the more advanced `useReducer` hook.

Read up on the docs on how to implement a reducer, make sure you:

1. don't change/mutate the state directly
2. change the state by dispatching `actions`
3. the reducer accepts the `current state` and the `action` and synchronously updates the state to the new state by the expression you `return`. Make use of the `switch` syntax to switch the various action types and `return` accordingly
4. label your actions sensibly, like: `{type: "new-row-added"}`, or `{type: "row-deleted", row: 2}`, or `{type: "row-updated", row: 3, update: { date: "2021-08-09" }}`

Learning the reducer pattern is very beneficial for more complicated state updates as it forces you to build an API for yourself, thus clarifying things.